# Android: OnTextChanged email validation is not working as expected

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, email-validation

I am using the fololowing code to validate the email input

```
  private boolean validateEmail(String email) {
        String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

I execute this on `onTextChanged`. The code is below (I am using `ButterKnife`)

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.et_email)
    public void checkCorrectEmail() {
        if (!validateEmail(mEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
            isValidated = false;
            mEditTextEmail.setError("Please enter email address");
            mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
        } else {
            isValidated = true;
        }
    }
```

The issue is that it is not intelligent enough. For an example, if I type `myemail@gmail.com` it still show the error message. However if I type `myemail@gmail.com` then a `space` and clicked delete the `space` then everything is fine, error gone.

Formerly this validation was on `onClick` of a button. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @OnTextChanged(R.id.et_email)
        public void checkCorrectEmail () {
            if (!validateEmail(mEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
                isValidated = false;
                mEditTextEmail.setError("Please enter email address");
                mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
            } else {
                isValidated = true;
                mEditTextEmail.setError(null);
            }
}
```

**100% working**

Comment: mEditTextEmail.setError(null); when email is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.et_email)
public void checkCorrectEmail() {
    if (!validateEmail(mEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
        isValidated = false;
        mEditTextEmail.setError("Please enter email address");
        mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
    } else {
        mEditTextEmail.setError(null)
        isValidated = true;
    }
}
```

clear the error on correct input

Comment: Gautam also answered the same time and its the solution

Comment: Time difference

Answer (score 1):

Use the in-build `Email` pattern checker method:

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.et_email)
public void checkCorrectEmail () {
if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mEditTextEmail.getText().toString()).matches()){
    isValidated = false;
    mEditTextEmail.setError("Please enter a Valid E-Mail Address!");
    mEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
}else {
    isValidated = true;
    mEditTextEmail.setError(null);
}
```